# AngularJS tagging directive like StackOverflow's tagging system

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

Any suggestion how to create the same auto-completion feature that Stack Overflow uses for entering tags?

I just have seen solutions like [SOTag (using jQuery)](http://www.iog3.com/322/so_tag-tagging-plugin-based-on-stackoverflows-tag-search/) but any solid alternative for AngularJS?

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear: You're looking for a stackoverflow-like tags input control, not just a regular one, right?

Comment: yeah it's the input control and the same style for the suggested tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) has an [AngularUI wrapper](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) and it handles tags pretty well. It might be a bit heavy if all you want is tagging as it's a complete `<select>` replacement, but it does what you need. Note that it also has `jQuery` as a dependency if that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can have the same functionality with Angular built-in filter. Check out the first example of this page http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Let me know if that's not what you mean.

Comment: I'm searching something like this implementation http://www.iog3.com/322/so_tag-tagging-plugin-based-on-stackoverflows-tag-search/ the filter could be an initial step for it, but there are a lot of more work to do to fill those requirements